# I ran dropna in dataframe but got an error message

Tags: python, dataframe

I ran this statement `dr=df.dropna(how='all')` to remove missing values and got the error message shown below:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-07367ab952bc> in <module>
----> 1 dr=df.dropna(how='all')

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dropna'
```

Comment: Your dataframe might not be a dataframe. Can you provide some sample data please?

Comment: Nan                             mpe1                pct1           mpe2
 1           Derivatives    31,410            7.57 %    NaN   
 2                    FX     8,036            1.94 %     Nan   
 3                 Total    44,695           10.77 %    43,037   
 
 
 0              pct2                      
 1             7.86 %        
 2             1.91 %       
 3            10.82 %

Comment: df = tabula.read_pdf(file, lattice=True, pages='all', area=(1, 1, 1000, 100), relative_area=True)
dr=df.dropna()

Comment: I generated df by running df = tabula.read_pdf(file, lattice=True, pages='all', area=(1, 1, 1000, 100), relative_area=True). So in this case, how do I make df a dataframe?

Comment: @user12794726, please add the sample date and code to your question and not within the comment section. Try to give all required data in your question

Answer (score 0):

According to pdf https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://readthedocs.org/projects/tabula-py/downloads/pdf/latest/&ved=2ahUKEwiKr-mQ9qTnAhUKwqYKHcAtAcoQFjADegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw32D890VNjAq5wOkTo4icOi&cshid=1580168098808

df = tabula.read_pdf(file, lattice=True, pages='all', area=(1, 1, 1000, 100), relative_area=True)

pages='all' =>  probably return  a list of Dataframe

So you have to check:

```
for sub_df in df:
   dr=sub_df.dropna(how='all')
```

Comment: Thank yo very much!